# While I am creating dataframe I am getting "Nullpointer Exception"

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am creating dataframe from another dataframe rows.
Which means I have a another dataframe ,Here that is named file_details.
That dataframe contains the rows ["srcpath","table_name","primary_key","type_of_file","separator"] in this
format.
I am creating one function.That function getting dataframe rows one by one.there i am checking the type of file.If it is csv Using Spark.read Option ,I have src_path and separator for that csv file.And i create a
dataframe ,And I write that dataframe into my sql server.Target table name ,and primary key also I got that in a single dataframe rows.In above i Have written the row structure.

This is the code i written.

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
object fixedlength {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("fixedlength")
      .master("local")
      .getOrCreate()
    val file_details=spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("////")
    def fun (ro:Row) : Unit= {         //Row like that ("srcpath","table_name","primary_key","type_of_file","separator")
      val url="jdbc:mysql://*****:3306/mydb1"
      val typ=ro.getString(3)
    if(typ=="csv")
         {

           val sep=ro.getString(4);
           val src_path=ro.getString(0);
           val tgt_table=ro.getString(1);
           val df1=spark.read.option("header", "true").option("delimiter",sep).csv(src_path)
           df1.write.format("jdbc")
             .mode("overwrite")
             .option("url",url)
             .option("driver","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
             .option("dbtable",tgt_table)
             .option("user","username")
             .option("password","password")
             .save()
          }
    }
   val ne=file_details.select("*").rdd.map(x=>fun(x)).collect()
}
}
```

Error I got,

```
    ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 7)
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fixedlength$.fixedlength$$fun$1(fixedlength.scala:66)
    at fixedlength$$anonfun$10.apply(fixedlength.scala:106)
    at fixedlength$$anonfun$10.apply(fixedlength.scala:106)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
21/04/12 11:11:09 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 7, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fixedlength$.fixedlength$$fun$1(fixedlength.scala:66)
    at fixedlength$$anonfun$10.apply(fixedlength.scala:106)
    at fixedlength$$anonfun$10.apply(fixedlength.scala:106)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

21/04/12 11:11:09 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
21/04/12 11:11:09 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 7.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
21/04/12 11:11:09 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 7
21/04/12 11:11:09 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Killing all running tasks in stage 7: Stage cancelled
21/04/12 11:11:09 INFO DAGScheduler: ResultStage 7 (collect at fixedlength.scala:106) failed in 0.156 s due to Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 7, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fixedlength$.fixedlength$$fun$1(fixedlength.scala:66)
    at fixedlength$$anonfun$10.apply(fixedlength.scala:106)
    at fixedlength$$anonfun$10.apply(fixedlength.scala:106)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
21/04/12 11:11:09 INFO DAGScheduler: Job 7 failed: collect at fixedlength.scala:106, took 0.164149 s
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 7, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fixedlength$.fixedlength$$fun$1(fixedlength.scala:66)
    at fixedlength$$anonfun$10.apply(fixedlength.scala:106)
    at fixedlength$$anonfun$10.apply(fixedlength.scala:106)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1887)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1875)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1874)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1874)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2108)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2057)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2046)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:737)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2082)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:944)
    at fixedlength$.main(fixedlength.scala:106)
    at fixedlength.main(fixedlength.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at fixedlength$.fixedlength$$fun$1(fixedlength.scala:66)
    at fixedlength$$anonfun$10.apply(fixedlength.scala:106)
    at fixedlength$$anonfun$10.apply(fixedlength.scala:106)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:891)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1334)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:945)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:2101)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
21/04/12 11:11:09 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
21/04/12 11:11:09 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://LTIN236281.cts.com:4040
21/04/12 11:11:09 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
21/04/12 11:11:10 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
21/04/12 11:11:10 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
21/04/12 11:11:10 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
21/04/12 11:11:10 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
21/04/12 11:11:10 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
21/04/12 11:11:10 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
21/04/12 11:11:10 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\844605\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-cae157ad-b63e-43b4-831e-9cc61094b4db
```

I have searched that error " Null pointer Exception " in internet .I found somewhere that says This error will throw when worker node tries to access spark context object.

Is there any different ways to achieve thing?

Can you please anyone help me to get out of this error?

My case study is, I just have a dataframe It contains src_path of file,type_of_file,if it is csv separator for that file,target table in sql. I passed these rows into one function i created it gets these parameters based on that it creates the dataframe and push that dataframe into the sql target table .I write these code inside the function.while iam run that i got "null pointer exception".

Comment: I didnt understand your points.

Comment: which dataframe need to change into list

Comment: If file_details dataframe is not so big you could change it to list and create the dataframe from each element in list

Comment: But the problem is Inside the function .there i create a new dataframe "df1".there only i am accessing spark object.isn't it?

Comment: Here `file_details.select("*").rdd.map(x=>fun(x))` the map function runs on executor and spark session is initialized in driver thats why you cannot access in executors

Comment: in first point you said Sparksession cannot be used on driver. Which means?

Comment: It is working but i need to know why before it is not working. 
 file_details.select("*").rdd.map(x=>fun(x))   but in this line i didn't use "sparksession" word.Then how you say map function access the spark session ?

Comment: Really sorry, that was a typo, I mean to say Sparksession cannot be used on executor, sorry for not double checking it,

Comment: Let me explain it again, `file_details.select("*").rdd.map(x=>fun(x))` here the map function in executed in each executor the function fun is also run in each executor, You used the spark session in function `func` which is created in each executor which is not possible, Hope this helps!

Comment: by avoiding map function , the "fun" function is runs in a driver. is it correct?

Comment: yes, correct but how would you replace map function. If you convert dataframe to list then use map function this map will run only on driver again.

Comment: i want to trim all dataframe columns in spark what should i do?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by trim dataframe, If you have a different issue please ask different question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67107840/15181363

Comment: there i post that question? could you please help me?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67107840/15181363

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67109327/15181363 could you please this question too?

Comment: The answer is given in the link there, have you checked it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67211316/15181363  Please koiralo