# How can we Convert RDD[Array[String]] into RDD[(String,String,String,String)]?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I recently I working on Spark.

There i need to perform trim operation for spark dataframe all columns.

If we know the column names , yes we can manually `withcolumn[trim()]` perform that.

But if we dont know the column names , how do we achieve that?.

So i searched this in web,in somewhere i found ,first convert rdd and perform then again convert into Dataframe.

withthe help of this ,I write one function it gets dataframe rows and perform trim operation each column in row.it accumulates this column result in one array.

finally it returns an array .trimmed row.

It will be same as all the rows in dataframe.

after that I create a two dimensional array,It is like a dataframe.Structure Like that `Array[Array[String]]`.and i accumulates these array rows from function in this two dimensional array.

And after `sc.parallalize()`with the help of this function i create a `RDD[Array[String]]`

But the problem is when i convert into dataframe.

```
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|[/Desktop/demo.tx...|
|[/Desktop/mobile....|
|[/Desktop/metadat...|
|[/Desktop/Employe...|
+--------------------+
```

Row of array assigned into one column.

But when we do map function

```
df.map(x=>(x(0),x(1),x(2),x(3))


+--------------------+------------+-----------+---+
|                  _1|          _2|         _3| _4|
+--------------------+------------+-----------+---+
|C:/Users//O.........|fruits_table|         Id|pos|
|C:/Users//O.........|      mobile|         id|csv|
|C:/Users//O.........|    metadata|column_name|csv|
|C:/Users//O.........|    employee|      EmpId|pos|
+--------------------+------------+-----------+---+
```

That is what i want.

the problem is i want to convert `RDD[Array[String]]` into `RDD[(String,String,String,String)]`

If anyone knows the answer please let me know?Thank You

Comment: We know the column size we do a map function .But if we dont know The column size how do we achieve that?

Comment: I don't think useing sc.parallalize() to create a dataframe is a good way for large amount of data, Also You can't extract the values if you don't know the size of the array.

Comment: It would be better to share your input data and expected dataframe there could be other better ways to read the data